# mysql order by first field and after for second field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-order-by

I have a query like this

```
select YEARWEEK(v.dataorainizio,1) yw,pdv.nome ,pdv.localita
from visita v
join pdv on pdv.id=v.idpdv
order by yw DESC
```

the result is

```
"yw"    |                               "nome"|"localita"

"202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202010"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Genova Ex Saturn"|"Genova"
"202010"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202009"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202009"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"Media World Asti"|"Asti"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202007"|"Media World Bergamo 2 - Orio"|"Orio Al Serio"
"202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202007"|"Media World Asti"|"Asti"
"202006"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
"202006"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
```

I would like to order for yw DESC but with subset of "nome" in order like this

```
    "202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202011"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"       
    "202010"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202009"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202009"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"      
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202008"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202007"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"      
    "202006"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202006"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Brescia 2"|"Brescia"
    "202010"|"( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Genova Ex Saturn"|"Genova"
    "202008"|"Media World Asti"|"Asti"
    "202007"|"Media World Asti"|"Asti"
    "202007"|"Media World Bergamo 2 - Orio"|"Orio Al Serio"
```

DB Version MariaDB 10.4

it's  possible without stored procedure and without post process result in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
order by nome desc, yw desc
```

If you want to put the `nome` with the most recet `yw` first, then, assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
order by
    max(yearweek(v.dataorainizio,1)) over(partition by pdv.nome) desc,
    yearweek(v.dataorainizio,1) desc
```

Comment: sorry i've double checked you answer with a different set of data and the result is not as expected

 `
    202017 ( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Napoli 2 Napoli
    202017 ( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Napoli 2 Napoli
    202017 ( PDV CHIUSO )Media World Nola Nola
    202013 ( PDV CHIUSO ) Media World Napoli 2 Napoli
    202012 ( PDV CHIUSO )Media World Nola Nola

Comment: solved using max(v.dataorainizio) instead of max(yearweek(v.dataorainizio,1))

thank you